# How to install Skipfish Security scanner under windows 7?

Tags: windows, security

I have a development PC with Windows 7 (APACHE / MYSQL / PHP) and I want to install "Skipfish" (http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/) in order to check my web app for security/vulnerability issues. I read the instructions but I can't understand it.

Comment: What, specifically, did you not understand?

Comment: The instructions say: "To compile it, simply unpack the archive and try make. Chances are, you will need to install libidn first." I  don't see any .exe file or anything that can could be executed.Do I need to use the CMD? The commands seem that is coming for a Linux Shell.

Comment: Install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to run Linux commands in Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cite the source page

> The tool is believed to support Linux, FreeBSD, MacOS X, and Windows (Cygwin) environments

Since it isn't a "real" windows application you don't have any file windows can execute (such as a .exe or .msi file). You need to use the http://www.cygwin.com/ tool and then more or less use it as an Linux application.

Read up on the instructions on skipfish and Cygwin, and then return with any more specific questions you may have.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is too late, but... Complied version is here: https://didasec.wordpress.com/2012/12/17/skipfish-2-10b-for-windows/

Since the original source is not available so it is shared in GDrive. Use it.
[Skipfish for Windows](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yz8274DkkSKeVDP1KHEgmRc8p_v41fR5/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi Zsolt. The link is dead, didasec.wordpress.com is down. Do you have an updated location? Otherwise please delete the answer.

Comment: http://shinnai.altervista.org/tools.html (from the deleted answer) is still working.